# Hoshanot Order in Sukkot

Tags: minhag, sukkot, hoshanos

In Nusach Sfard (Ashkenazi) there are different Hoshanot at the different days of Sukkot. Why does the order and the content of the Hoshanot depend on the day of the first Sukkot Yom Tov? Is there any connection between the content of the Hoshanot of specific day to the order of the day of Sukkot? Why is there different Hoshanot to each day?

Comment: https://jerroldlandau.com/piyutHoshana6.php

Comment: There used to be dozens of piyyutim and dozens of customs how to order them including places that picked different orders every time. The one in your siddur is the one some publisher picked a few centuries ago and became popular since it was in the popular siddurim.

Comment: See too Aruch Hashulchan 663 after questioning if the printed hoshana order really makes sense אך אין משיבין על המנהג בדבר שעל פי דין אין שום עיכוב, אם כה ואם כה it doesn't really matter the order so why fight about it